# JPA Persistence with Jersey without Injection

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jersey, jax-rs

I'm developing a REST API with jersey. Now I have to persist the entities with JPA and as I learned in university I "openend" a DB Connection with the following code:

```
EntityManagerFactory factory = javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("LootDB");
EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
```

I'm using the code above in EVERY RESOURCE. But I think this is a bad design. Because I don't know about Spring and dependency injection, I have to create the persistence instances manually.

Is there something wrong? In the database I can observe just 2 openened connections and I never get concurrency issues.

any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

You can define a class which spring bean scope is singleton.For accessing that class instance use @Autowired annotation.After that you can access the factory instance with it in everywhere.